# How to run AWS command in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to get the VPC ID in ansible and pass it into the next task, I have the statement in playbook:

```
- name: TO DISPLAY VPC ID
     command: ID=`aws ec2 describe-vpcs --filter Name=tag:Name,Values=ANSIBLE_VPC --query Vpcs[].VpcId --output text`
```

then getting the error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "'ID=`aws' ec2 describe-vpcs --filter Name=tag:Name,Values=ANSIBLE_VPC --query 'Vpcs[].VpcId' --output 'text`'", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
```

How can I run that command and then pass that $ID into the next task where it will be use for subnets, routers, IGW,   etc.....

Comment: the lines in the play-book I have:

Comment: name: TO DISPLAY VPC ID

Comment: command: command: ID=`aws ec2 describe-vpcs --filter Name=tag:Name,Values=ANSIBLE_VPC --query Vpcs[].VpcId --output text`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add some explanation or code instead of using comments as you did.

Comment: I strongly suggest you first have a look to the [numerous amazon cloud modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_cloud_modules.html#amazon) (more precisely all `ec2_vpc_*_info` modules) before you try to run raw commands directly. I'm almost sure one of them can fulfill your current requirement in an easier, safer, more predictable and idempotent way.

Answer (score 0):

ansible complains as it cannot find the command you provided `ID=aws ...`

what you should do is to execute the `aws` command and register resutl for further access

so

```
- name: TO DISPLAY VPC ID 
  command: aws ec2 describe-vpcs --filter Name=tag:Name,Values=ANSIBLE_VPC --query Vpcs[].VpcId --output text
  register: ID
```

from now on you can use `ID` variable in other scripts

Comment: thank you, I am using it, but still getting the error :   was running below:

Comment: # TO DISPLAY VPC ID BELOW:
   - name: TO DISPLAY VPC ID
     command: aws ec2 describe-vpcs --filter Name=tag:Name,Values=ANSIBLE_VPC --query Vpcs[].VpcId --output text
     register: VPC_ID
     #command: echo $VPC_ID

Comment: # TO CREATE NEW PUBLIC SUBNET BELOW:
 # we have set map_public to YES.. This means instances created in this subnet is associated with a public IP address.
   - name: associate PUBLIC subnet to the VPC
     ec2_vpc_subnet:
       state: present
       vpc_id: "{{ VPC_ID }}"
       region:  us-east-1
       cidr: 10.0.0.1/24
       map_public: yes
       resource_tags:
         Name: ANSIBLE_VPC__us-east-1__10.0.0.1__PUBLIC
       register: subnet

Comment: but getting the error:   Unsupported parameters for (ec2_vpc_subnet) module: register Supported parameters include: aws_access_key,aws_secret_key,az,cidr,ec2_url,map_public,profile,region,security_token,state,tags,validate_certs,vpc_id"}

Comment: I exported my keys before running that script

Comment: getting the other error, that I do not understand, for creating subnet:

Comment: n exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ClientError: An error occurred (FilterLimitExceeded) when calling the DescribeSubnets operation: The maximum length for a filter value is 255 characters
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "error": {"code": "FilterLimitExceeded", "message": "The maximum length for a filter value is 255 characters"}, "msg": "An error occurred (FilterLimitExceeded) when calling the DescribeSu

Comment: nets operation: The maximum length for a filter value is 255 characters", "response_metadata": {"http_headers": {"connection": "close", "date": "Mon, 16 Dec 2019 19:11:56 GMT", "server": "AmazonEC2", "transfer-encoding": "chunked"}, "http_status_code": 400, "request_id": "8b89f47e-8814-40ca-9cgg-6c5cadf722bc", "retry_attempts": 0}}